# Jenkins Using Different Environment From Host

Tags: ruby, jenkins, rubygems

Is there a way to get Jenkins to use the same environment set up as the host it runs on?

When I log onto the host node that Jenkins runs on, and execute the command `/usr/local/bin/fpm --version`, I get back **1.12.0**.

However, when I execute the same command `/usr/local/bin/fpm --version` via a shell command directly in Jenkins I get the error

```
/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'fpm' (>= 0) among 0 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'
    from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
    from /usr/local/bin/fpm:22:in `<main>'
```

When I run `gem environment` on the host machine, I get

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.14.1
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2015-12-16 patchlevel 648) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/share/gems
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/share/gems
     - /root/.gem/ruby
     - /usr/share/gems
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
```

When I run the same in Jenkins through a shell command, I get something different

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.14.1
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2015-12-16 patchlevel 648) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /var/lib/jenkins/.gem/ruby
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /var/lib/jenkins/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /var/lib/jenkins/.gem/ruby
     - file
     - /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/ruby-runtime/WEB-INF/lib/stapler-jruby-1.209.jar!/gem/
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
```

And I'm not sure if this is what's causing the problem.

I've tried exporting `GEM_HOME` to `/usr/local/share/gems` to match what's on the host, but I get the same error.

Is there a way to get the same output for `/usr/local/bin/fpm --version` on both Jenkins and the node it runs on?

Comment: /usr/local/share/gems not a GEM PATHS on jenkins but you can configured that again it's not a good option better you can install rvm on your machine and create gemset on it then configure your jenkins jobs to use that gemset.